# Voting does not show up

Tags: rating, 7

I am using "[answers module](https://www.drupal.org/project/answers)".

The voting does not appear on the screen even I've enabled "[rate module](https://www.drupal.org/project/rate)".
I changed the settings of Rate Widget and disabled the rate module and re-enabled it, but nothing changed.